# How can I add number of non 0 observations of each group in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I need to add number of non 0 observations above each bar in the graph. i have included packages and code. I am not sure what else to add that would be helpful. Thank you

```
library('dplyr')
library('tidyr')
library('ggplot2')
library('tidyr')
library('EnvStats')
library('RColorBrewer')
library('ggrepel')

mean.ind.exp <- structure(list(name = structure(c(13L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 8L, 14L, 
5L, 10L, 7L), levels = c("advertising", "atv.tractor", "bred.does", 
"capital.improvements", "DMP.compliance", "equipment.maintenance", 
"hospitality", "land.managment", "other", "payroll", "property.taxes", 
"stocker.bucks", "supplemental.feed.food.plots", "surveys"), class = "factor"), 
    dollars = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), mean.dollars = c(2286, 
    1802, 11, 4292, 452, 1350, 37, 4, 669, 280)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), groups = structure(list(
    name = structure(c(1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 10L, 13L, 
    14L), levels = c("advertising", "atv.tractor", "bred.does", 
    "capital.improvements", "DMP.compliance", "equipment.maintenance", 
    "hospitality", "land.managment", "other", "payroll", "property.taxes", 
    "stocker.bucks", "supplemental.feed.food.plots", "surveys"
    ), class = "factor"), .rows = structure(list(3L, 4L, 2L, 
        8L, 5L, 10L, 6L, 9L, 1L, 7L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -10L), .drop = TRUE))
```

```
library(ggplot2)
ind.exp <- ggplot(mean.ind.exp, aes(reorder(name, -mean.dollars),mean.dollars)) + geom_bar(stat = "summary", alpha = 1) + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::label_dollar(), expand=expansion(mult=c(0,0.1))) + 
   scale_x_discrete(labels=c('ATV/Tractor','Supp. Feed/Food Plots','Capital Improvements', 'Land Management', 'Property Taxes', 'Payroll','Equip. Maintenance', 'Hospitality', 
                            'Stocker Bucks','Bred Does','Other Expenses','Wildlife Surveys', 'Advertising','DMP Compliance')) +                         #'
                           
  labs(title='White-tailed Deer Related Landowner Expenses', y = "Avg. Spent", x= 'Expense')  +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size=30, face="bold"), axis.text.x = element_text(size=30, colour = "black", angle = 30, vjust=0.5), 
        axis.text.y = element_text(size=30, colour = "black"), axis.title = element_text(size=30, face='bold')) +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")) +
  theme(plot.margin = margin(2, 4, 2, 2, "cm")) +
  stat_n_text(y.po=4200, color='black')
ind.exp
```

Comment: Where does the `stat_n_text` function come from?

Comment: The ```stat_n_text``` function was something I found in ```EnvStats``` and tried. It presents total observations for each category, but I need

Comment: What should be the desired output for each bar?

Comment: Each category has 2763 observations, but many of those observations are for $0. I would like to show how many in each category are > $0.

Answer (score 0):

The data you provided is already grouped and summarized which means we cannot extract the number of observations >$0 from it, so I made some up to represent something akin to your data prior to the summary step you must have performed to arrive at your `mean.ind.exp` object. You will have to incorporate this prior to the producing those data you provided in your example.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(dollars=sample(seq(0,4000,50),2763,replace = T),
             name=sample(c("advertising", "atv.tractor", "bred.does", 
                           "capital.improvements", "DMP.compliance", "equipment.maintenance", 
                           "hospitality", "land.managment", "other", "payroll", "property.taxes", 
                           "stocker.bucks", "supplemental.feed.food.plots", "surveys"),
                         2763,replace = T)) 

df2 <- df %>%  group_by(name) %>% 
  summarise(mean_dollars=mean(dollars),
            n_0=sum(dollars>0))  %>% ungroup()
```

Then to put the labels from the data above the columns you can use `geom_text` and add the `label` aesthetic.

```
ggplot(data = df2,
       aes(x=name,y=mean_dollars)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(aes(label=n_0), vjust=-0.5) # This is the label layer
```