# How do I add TukeyHSD results from multcompLetters function to an interaction plot in R?

Tags: r, tukey, interaction-plot

I've ran a single-factor ANOVA on my data set and followed that with a TukeyHSD post-hoc test. I then used multcompLetters() to assign letters to the significant TukeyHSD results. I'm now trying to add the letters to an interaction plot. However, I can't seem to figure out a way to do this and have looked at several examples using boxplots but I am still lost. Any help or suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Here is the code I have used so far;

Below is a sample of data from the code I used - I am looking at whether poker player skill and/or the quality of the poker hand impact the amount of earnings in a poker game.

```
head(poker)

    Skill   Hand    Limit  Earnings
    <chr>  <chr>    <chr>  <dbl>
1   Expert  Bad     Fixed   4.00
2   Average Bad     Fixed   5.55
3   Expert  Good    Fixed   9.45
4   Average Good    Fixed   7.19
5   Expert  Neutral Fixed   5.71
6   Average Neutral Fixed   5.32

# read in the csv file
poker <- read.csv("poker_skill.csv", header=T)

# create a model including an interaction
mod1 = lm(Earnings~Hand + Skill + Hand:Skill, data = poker)
Anova(mod1, type = "3")

# Performa Tukey's HSD test on mod1
TukeyHSD(aov(mod1))

# Use the multcompLetters4() function in the multcompView package to assign letters to 
the significant results
Letters <- multcompLetters4(mod1, TukeyHSD(aov(mod1)), reversed = TRUE)
Letters

# Create an interaction plot and then add the Letters to the plot
pokerInt <- poker %>%
  group_by(Hand,Skill) %>%
  summarise(mean=mean(Earnings)
        
ggplot(poker, aes(x=factor(Hand), y=Earnings, colour=Skill)) +
  geom_point(data=pokerInt, aes(y=mean)) +
  geom_line(data=pokerInt, aes(y=mean, group=Skill)) +
  labs(x="Poker Hand", y="Poker Earnings") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

I am unsure on how I can add the Letters to the above interaction plot

Comment: The use of `geom_text()` may work for you. You can see an example here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75761561/need-to-display-geom-col-labels-above-bar-as-n-a-when-they-are-0/75761679#75761679 with a column plot and built in data. You can adapt the `labeldata` object for your specific needs. Note that you can, and likely should  in your case create a separate dataframe for the labels rather than using labels from the same one as used for plotting as here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75769002/how-can-i-add-number-of-non-0-observations-of-each-group-in-ggplot/75771519#75771519

Comment: Hey, I think this answer may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70854552/any-other-options-besides-the-traditional-cld-bar-graph/70863531#70863531

Answer (score 1):

You can add compact letters to your ggplot function using `geom_text()`. To do this you need some manipulation of the output from `multcompLetters4()` and later you could join the resulting compact letter output to your summary data containing means and letters `(pokerInt)`. To show how to do this, I just created a random sample based on your data and adding few more rows. The example data `(poker)` used to produce here can be found below.

**Create a model including an interaction**

```
library(tidyverse)

mod1 = lm(Earnings~Hand + Skill + Hand:Skill, data = poker)
summary(mod1)

car::Anova(mod1, type = "3")
```

**Use the `multcompLetters4()` function in the multcompView package to assign letters to**

```
library(multcomp);library(multcompView)
Letters <- multcompLetters4(mod1, TukeyHSD(aov(mod1)), 
reversed = TRUE)
```

**Provide summary data including `means` of groups**

```
pokerInt <- poker %>%
  group_by(Hand,Skill) %>%
  summarise(mean=mean(Earnings))
```

**Adding the compact letter display to the table**

```
tukey.cld <- as.data.frame.list(Letters$`Hand:Skill`)
```

**Adding interaction levels to corresponding letters to join with summary data**

```
tukey.cld$Levels <- rownames(tukey.cld) ; rownames(tukey.cld) <- NULL

tukey.cld <- select(tukey.cld,Levels,Letters)
tukey.cld <- separate(tukey.cld, col = "Levels", into = 
c("Hand","Skill"), sep = ":",remove = T)
```

**Join letters with summary data `(pokerInt)` for plotting**

```
pokerInt <- left_join(pokerInt, tukey.cld, by=c("Hand", "Skill"))
```

**Here the `pokerInt` contains both means and letters and can be passed to `ggplot` function**

```
pokerInt

  Hand    Skill   mean Letters
  Bad     Average  6.28    abc    
  Bad     Expert   3.5     a      
  Good    Average  8.04    bc     
  Good    Expert   9.07    c      
  Neutral Average  5.41    ab     
  Neutral Expert   6.10    abc
```

**Now we could add the compact letters to plot using `geom_text()`. You can play with `vjust` and `hjust` to adjust the position of letters**

```
ggplot(poker, aes(x=factor(Hand), y=Earnings, colour=Skill)) +
          geom_point(data=pokerInt, aes(y=mean)) +
          geom_line(data=pokerInt, aes(y=mean, group=Skill)) +
          geom_text(data=pokerInt
                    , aes(y=mean, label=Letters)
                    , position = position_dodge(0.90), size = 3.5, 
                    , vjust= 0.0, hjust= -0.3
                    , colour = "gray25"
                    , fontface = "bold")+
          labs(x="Poker Hand", y="Poker Earnings") +
          theme_bw()
```

**And finally the plot with the compact letters:**
[image]

**The example data**

```
poker <- read.table(text = "Skill   Hand    Limit   Earnings
Expert  Bad Fixed   4
Average Bad Fixed   5.55
Expert  Good    Fixed   9.45
Average Good    Fixed   7.19
Expert  Neutral Fixed   5.71
Average Neutral Fixed   5.32
Expert  Bad Fixed   3
Average Bad Fixed   7
Expert  Good    Fixed   8.7
Average Good    Fixed   8.9
Expert  Neutral Fixed   6.5
Average Neutral Fixed   5.5
",header=T)
```